# dynamic select list AJAX and insertion in database table through posting form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am wondering to find a solution for my dynamic select list of cities, now I am successfully populated the cities but now unable to post the selected city to database.

here is php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="show_cities.js"> </script> 
</head>
<body>
<?php 
session_start;
//library   
include("conn.php");
?>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='posting_process.php' method='post'>");
<!-- **************************** Country select list ********************** -->
Country: 
<select name="country" onChange="showCities(this.value)">
<?php $sql = 'SELECT country_no, country_name FROM country '.'ORDER BY country_no';
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<option value='0'>"."Select a Country"."</option>\n  ";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
echo "<option value=\"".$row['country_no']."\">".$row['country_name']."</option>\n  ";
    }
?>
</select>
City: <div id="txtCity" class="city_no">
<input type=submit name=action value=Post>
</body>
</html>
```

here is javascript: show_cities.js

```
// JavaScript Document
/* <script type="text/javascript"> */
function showCities(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtCity").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_cities.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
/* </script> */
```

here is php file: get_cities.php

```
<?php
session_start;
//library   
include("conn.php");
$q=$_GET["q"];

$sql="SELECT * FROM city WHERE country_no = ".$q;
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='city'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<option value=\"".$row['city_no']."\">".$row['city_name'] . "</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

I don't know how to mention the following  which return / display the city
    
regards:

Comment: What happens when you submit the form ? Have you checked using Firebug?

Comment: nothing happens. the insert statement executed and all the values inserted in table with out this (city_no) one.

Comment: Not sure if this will resolve this issue. I have noted two things in your html mark-up 1. Form tag is not closed and <div id="txtCity" class="city_no"> is also not closed. Correct the same. Use firebug check the values that are passed while submitting the page.

Comment: thanks for your reply. both are closed now. in chrome / inspect on the form page the values are correct. but on submit all the values go correct but city is not inserted in table.

Comment: this tutorial http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html solved my problem. Thanks to all you people.

Comment: Glad to know that you are able to resolve the issue. And +1 for posting the link. This might someone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the jQuery Ajax to send the data to the backend php code and receive the response. 
Your php code seems fine, I would suggest to use the following mechanism to work with ajax.

Please add id as "countrylist" to your country list in the front end html page.

And use the following code instead of your javascript for ajax calls.

```
$(function (){
    $('#countrylist').change(function() {
        var sel_val=$("#countrylist").val();
        $.ajax({
           url: 'get_cities.php?q='+sel_val,
           success: function(data) {
             $('#txtCity').html(data);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Also make sure you have added the jquery libraries before adding this javascript code.

Hope this helps.

Thanks